# Eclipse Indigo RSE/TM and remote sync

Tags: php, rsync, eclipse-pdt

I look around on StackOverflow and found similar but not this question exactly, so I come here for help.

I'm working on a PHP Project using Eclipse Indigo (3.7.1) + PDT 3.0.0 . In my case, my development is done locally, but testing the page is done on a remote server, authentication done by an SSH2 key. As of now I run, parallel to Eclipse, WinSCP with the Keep Remote Directory Up-to-date enable, so everytime I save a file on Eclipse, it uploads to the server. I wanted to do that inside Eclipse.

I installed the RSE/TM package and manage to use the view to browse the files on the remote server, but I didn't find anywhere on how to sync with the remote server automatically. Ideally I would be able to let the project sync everytime I save the file.

Can you guys help?

Answer (score 0):

In Remote System Explorer perspective, find the folder on the remote machine you'd like to sync to. Right click on it -> `Export from project`